# Drupal 8: Composer install issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, composer-php

I have 2 AWS EC2 instances (servers).

I have same code on both servers.

> On 1st server I have composer version 1.7.2. Which works FINE.
>
> On 2nd server I have composer version 1.9.3. Which is not working fine.

So on 2nd server when I run `composer install` it will not install some of the modules & it is not applying some of that patches which I have applied for code.

I don't think so it is version issue.

Comment: I think that this question could be hardly answered by someone which is not an AWS internal or has experienced (and solved) the exact same problem. There is simply not enough information here to make some sort of educated guess... Providing logs of running the composer install command would be a good starting point.

Comment: not enough info.. you could share the actual error message.. so we have something to work with..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is it's missing

```
yum install patch
```